# Android UI reliant on data from webservice - data doesn't come back in time

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a screen in my application that is just a bunch of links.  I am being directed to get the URLs from a web service so that they can be changed whenever and no android code would have to change. My problem is though I ask for data from AsyncTask and it does not come back before the user access the screen and then the links are either not there, or go back to a hardcoded resource I put in.  Is there a better way to get data that affects the app like this?

Answer (score 0):

why not just put in a progress dialog and then dismiss it in the `onPostExecute`? that way the link is always there and they cannot get ahead of the call

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea to cache the links, so that the screen isn't blank, at least after the first time you run the app. You can update the list every time the user opens the page.